# UI Automation - Karate DSL unable to identify locators of HTML file

Tags: karate

Feature: Locate elements of HTML page instead http URL

```
Background:
```

- configure driver = {type:'chromedriver' , executable:'D:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe'}

Scenario:
Given driver 'D:/APIs/test-iframe.html'

- driver.maximize()
- waitUntil("document.readyState == 'complete'")
- waitFor('#txt-username')
- input('#txt-username', 'John Doe')

Comment: If it is URL then Karate DSL able to interact with locators. But if it is HTML file instead of URL then Karate DSL unable to identify locators. But we can inspect those locators.

Above code worked till: 
waitUntil("document.readyState == 'complete'")

But later on it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, an HTML file loaded from the file system will NOT behave like a web-page and some things you expect will not work.

You may have to run a web-server and then use that to serve the file.

If you have python installed, that may be a very [quick way to do it](https://ryanblunden.com/create-a-http-server-with-one-command-thanks-to-python-29fcfdcd240e).

Karate can [do it as well](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/examples/ui-test) with some more work.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas for your quick reply. I will try to create this HTML page in the form of web-server with either one of the option as above mentioned by you.

Comment: Hi Peter, I need to extract response from XHR API call after I clicked on "Complete Your Reservation" page. PFA screenshot for it.

Comment: @JeetendraEdke sorry my opinion is you are asking for too much. read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask